# Finding confidence level given confidence interval and sample size

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

Question:

> The Austin-American Statesman asked an SRS of 100 Austinites for their opinion about Mayor Adler's performance. Using the results of the sample, the C% confidence interval for the proportion of all Austinites who approve of the mayor's job performance is .565 to .695. What is the value of C?
>
> A) 82
>
> B) 86
>
> C) 90
>
> D) 95
>
> E) 99

To do this, I set up the equation to get the confidence interval:

> Confidence interval = $.63 \pm z \cdot \sqrt{\dfrac{0.63 \cdot 0.37}{100}}$

Solving for z gives around 91%...

Am I doing this right?

Comment: I think so, but given only 100 people you might need to get the confidence interval/formula for a t-distribution, not the normal distribution.

Comment: @eSurfsnake I think so. So the t-score would be 1.346, and this corresponds to 82%

Comment: @JenkinsMa Why you get so different answers by using the normal distribution(91%) and the t-distribution (82%). It doesn´t make sense.

Answer (score 1):

In R, `pnorm((.695-.63)/sqrt(.63*.37/100))` returns
0.9108973, as you say, but that is not quite the end of the story.

This implies that the upper confidence value cuts about 9% from the upper tail. Similarly, the lower value cuts about 9% from the lower tail. So the *confidence level* is about 82%.

Furthermore, `qnorm(c(.09, .91))` returns
$\pm 1.340755$ as the z-values to use in an 82% CI
of the form $$\hat p \pm 1.341\sqrt{\frac{\hat p(1-\hat p)}{n}}.$$

Then we have $(0.565, 0.695)$ as an 82% confidence
interval for the binomial success probability $p;$
the computation using R as a calculator is shown below:

```
p.hat = .63;  n = 100;  c = 1.341;  pm = c(-1,1)
p.hat + pm*c*sqrt(p.hat*(1-p.hat)/n)
[1] 0.5652559 0.6947441
```

I agree with @callculus that appeal to a t-distribution in this context makes no sense.
However, with $n = 100$ and 99 degrees of freedom, there is little difference between Student's t
distribution and standard normal. So your Comment is on the right track toward an 82% interval.

*Note:* A Jeffreys 82% Bayesian probability interval is $(0.564, 0.692).$ This interval, based on a non-informative prior is often numerically similar to the frequentist Wilson interval. Both the Jeffreys interval (used as a frequentist CI) and the Wilson interval have more accurate coverage probabilities than the Wald interval shown above, especially for $n$ as small as 100.

```
qbeta(c(.09,.91), 63.5, 37.5)
[1] 0.5637247 0.6923295
```